# Running rails app both as engine and app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-engines

I'm transforming a Rails application (say appA) into engine so that I can hook it into another Rails app (say appB). However **appA must run as a Rails app solely as well**. That's because a customer can buy

1. appA or
2. appB with appA. There is no option of buying only appB.

Following [rails oficial guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html) I made (among others) following changes:

- Changed `Rails.application.routes.draw` to `ActionPlan::Engine.routes.draw` in `routes.rb`.
- Created `lib/action_plan/engine.rb` with content shown below:

  ```
  module ActionPlan
    class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
      isolate_namespace ActionPlan
    end
  end
  ```

Now when I run `rails s` I get `/action_plan/config/routes.rb:1:in '<top (required)>': uninitialized constant ActionPlan::Engine (NameError)`.

I guess I should initialize `ActionPlan::Engine` in `application.rb` file somehow but I don't know how neither whether it's the way to go.

So is it possible to build an app/engine in rails such as appA? If it is, how can I overcome that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some researching and talking to some friends, I found out that it's not possible to do such a think with rails, but it's possible you to create another rails app (say appC) and use it only to run your engine, i.e appC is a silly rails app used only to make it possible to run your engine.